# Appium - How to get all views in an Android scroll view

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to figure out how to get all elements in a ListView/ScrollView. Appium isn't able to get invisible elements in ListView. AndroidDriver only has method scrollTo(String), but that's if I know what Im looking for, not when I simply try to get a list of everything that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do it.

`List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id(widgetId));//replace widget id with actual widget id`

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. This method doesn't account for invisible elements